# Using concat & scalar variable SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, concatenation

I have a problem when I want to use `CONCAT` inside my stored procedure. I press execute and get this error message:

> Mens 195, Nivel 15, Estado 10, Procedimiento upd_agregar, Línea 96
>   CONCAT is not a recognized built-in function name.

This is my table:

```
create table sucursales
(
    idSucursal  nvarchar(5) primary key,
    idEmpresa   int not null,
    sucursal    nvarchar(25) not null,
    direccion   nvarchar(100) not null,
    telefono    nvarchar(25),
    email       nvarchar(25) not null,
    constraint fk_suc_emp foreign key(idEmpresa) 
                references empresas(idEmpresa)
)
```

This is my query:

```
create procedure upd_agregar
    (@idEmpresa int, 
     @sucursal nvarchar(25),
     @direccion nvarchar(100),
     @telefono nvarchar (25),
     @email nvarchar(25))
as
    declare @longitud int, @codEmpresa nvarchar(2),@codSucursal nvarchar (2)

--Generar codigo de empresa
IF len(@idEmpresa) < 2
    SET @codEmpresa = CONCAT ('0',@idEmpresa)
ELSE
    SET @codEmpresa = @idEmpresa
```

GO

and then when I want to make a select like this, I receive an error that I must declare a scalar variable @codSucursal:

```
SELECT @codSucursal = isnull(max(cast(substring (idSucursal,4,2)AS int)),0) + 1 FROM sucursales 
WHERE idEmpresa = @idEmpresa
```

Comment: What is compatibility level set for this database?

Comment: The compatibility level is 120

Comment: Can you declare @codSucursal nvarchar (2) with nvarchar(10)... whats string length it is returning from isnull.... Error looks strange

Comment: Please show us what is returned by `SELECT @@VERSION`.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.2000.8 (X64)